# kutils (where to find this specif package)

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm trying to reproduce this project [github](https://github.com/subpic/ava-mlsp).
I created a python environment using `virtualenv` with theses settings : (`Python 2.7.16`, `tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0`, `keras-gpu`) . But whenever i run the this [notebook](https://github.com/subpic/ava-mlsp/blob/master/predict_mlsp_wide.ipynb) i get the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-286bd3b6e5cd> in <module>()
      1 import kutils
----> 2 from kutils import model_helper as mh
      3 from kutils import applications as apps
      4 from kutils import tensor_ops as ops
      5 from kutils import generic as gen

ImportError: cannot import name model_helper
```

I tried using multiple historic releases of [kutils](https://pypi.org/project/kutils/#history) but got the same error with all of them so i'm sure it's not the right module.

so to sum up the question : *does anyone know how to install the adequate `kutils` to set up my environment correctly.*

Answer (score 0):

I found the specific package eventually, here's a link [kutils](https://github.com/subpic/kutils)